# Microsoft Graph - List all users with any app role assignment for specific resource (enterprise application)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to fetch a list of users who have any app role assigned on my enterprise application. Using `/servicePrincipal/{id}/appRolesAssignedTo` somewhat works, but returns users multiple times (once per role), and I would have to unroll transitive/group assignments manually.

It seems like this should be possible via `/users` using a filter but I am getting a strange error message when I attempt getting `/users?$filter=appRoleAssignments/any(a:a/resourceId eq {enterprise app obj id})`.

The request fails, but not with the generic `BadReuqest` which means you've messed up the syntax or types, but saying `appRoleAssignments/any(a:a/resourceId eq {enterprise app obj id})` even though it clearly does.

Filtering by `ge` or `le` using `createdDateTime` instead of `resourceId` does work, but provides unexpected results, not matching anything found in the actual objects when using `$expand=appRoleAssignments`. Also, filtering by `id` yields `Invalid object identifier` leading me to believe that whatever the type of `a:a` is, it is NOT in fact the same as the objects provided under `user/appRoleAssignments` (when expanded).

Filtering appRolesAssignments themselves for a specific user using the same syntax (i.e. `/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq {enterprise app obj id}` works just fine.

Can anyone please shed any light on this situation?

Comment: Been digging into these lately, I think this might not be supported yet, since I get the code 'Request_UnsupportedQuery'. I even tried a workaround. Since not every user has a role assigned, I first tried to just get users that have any AppRoleAssignments, but again to no avail since the $count operator doesn't seem to be working also.